# How can I make scala-maven-plugin recognize Cp1252 encoding?

Tags: scala, maven, encoding

I have several maven modules that use Cp1252 encoding.  I had no trouble with this encoding until I added scala to one of the modules.  The scala-maven-plugin ignores the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property and attempts to parse the source files as if they were UTF-8.

I tried adding the encoding to the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When that didn't work I tried adding the encoding to the executions too:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDir>${basedir}/scala</sourceDir>
                <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDir>${basedir}/scala</sourceDir>
                <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The module in question has 1454 source files, so converting the module to use UTF-8 is not practical.

Comment: scala-maven-plugin doesn't support mixed configuration from plugin and from execution (a bug in maven ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this solution:

```
<configuration>
    <args>
    <arg>-encoding</arg>
    <arg>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</arg>
    </args>
</configuration>
```

Not sure if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

from the doc  is for

> The -encoding argument for the Java compiler. (when using incremental compiler).

So it should not work in your case (not incremental + not java).

The solution of Gooseman is the right :

```
<configuration>
  <args>
    <arg>-encoding</arg>
    <arg>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</arg>
  </args>
</configuration>
```